# Ember Updating route to pull from store (Mirage)

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli-mirage

I am trying to follow the ember tutorial to set up mock data in development.
This is where I am reading from:
https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.5.0/tutorial/ember-data/

The tutorial is supposed to be showing me how to convert hard-coded data to mirage/config.js

I've gotten all the way to the bottom of the page, but it seems like it's missing a step. The .hbs, typed out on the previous page, has not been changed:

```
{{#each model as |rental|}}
  <h2>{{rental.title}}</h2>
  <p>Owner: {{rental.owner}}</p>
  <p>Type: {{rental.type}}</p>
  <p>Location: {{rental.city}}</p>
  <p>Number of bedrooms: {{rental.bedrooms}}</p>
{{/each}}
```

Which would be great except there's nothing in {{model}}.

I see in the console that I have received the json:

```
Successful request: GET /rentals
server.js:255 Object {data: Array[3]}
```

And all my routes and stuff are pointing correctly, as I can see in Ember inspector:

- Route Name: rentals
- Route: rentals
- Controller: rentals
- Template:  rentals
- URL: /rentals

But how do I access that data? What am I missing?

models/rentals.js:

```
import Model from 'ember-data/model';
export default Model.extend({
});
```

routes/rentals.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model() {
        return this.store.findAll('rental');
    }
});
```

mirage/config.js
export default function() {

```
export default function() {
    this.get('/users', function() {
        return {
            data: [{
                type: 'rentals',
                id: 4,
                attributes: {
                    name: 'Lodge',
                    etc...
                }
            }, {
                etc...
            }]
        };
    });
};
```

Comment: please post the content of the model of the ember route, if you don't mind

Comment: Updated question with file contents.

Comment: Install the Ember Inspector and see if the data made it from the mock response to your Ember Data store

Comment: Yes, the data made it. One call gets me all the records. What's killing me is that I don't even see the template, let alone a data record.